# How to prevent copy and paste in data validation column cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on excel VBA. I am binding the database data into excel drop down list.

Like i am binding 'English,French,German' languages into excel drop down dynamically.

Now my problem is whenever i am attempting to copy data from other sheet or other excel file then pasting into the cell the copied value is successfully pasting on the particular cell.
The the particular cell is loosing the data validation functionality.

Here i need to make the particular data validation column prevent copy and paste other values which are not listed in data list like below..

As i have mentioned that i am binding 'English,French,German'.but when i attempt to copy 'Spanish' the 'Spanish' is successfully pasted into the pasted cell.Now i don not want to paste the other values in to my cell.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Once you copy a range and do `Application.Paste` then all of the copied cell properties are also overwritten to the destination cell. So the destination cell will lose its validation rules if the copied cell had no validation.

You only need to copy the values of the cell to the destination cell, meaning that you want to keep all other properties, such as formatting, validation, etc.

In this case, you should `PasteSpecial` and paste values only

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it still bypasses the validation and allows any value to be input (at least it does when I try it). If you are using VBA I would do any validation in the worksheet_change event.